# Legal standpoint of using open source map data in proprietary software?

Tags: openstreetmap, legal

I am planning to use an API call to something like http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=... to gather raw GIS data for an application I am working on.

Can anyone tell me if that affects my ability to keep my code proprietary, or am I compelled to make my code open source (in a similar way to if I was using someone's GPL code, for example)?

Comment: Have you contacted the overpass-api.de site to see what licensing comes with using their software?

Comment: have you read and understood http://wiki.osmfoundation.org/wiki/License?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can keep all of your code private. [OSM's license](http://wiki.osmfoundation.org/wiki/License) only applies to its database, i.e. raw OSM data.

But beware: If you use raw OSM data and add own information to it then you are creating a *derivative database*. This derivative database then has to be made available under the same licence as OSM data (the [ODbL](http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/)).

And of course: IANAL. See the [Legal FAQ](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Legal_FAQ) for more information.